# Do shortcodes affect page indexing by search engines?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, seo

I am using [this(Insert PHP Code Snippet)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) plugin for inserting PHP code in a HTML page.

My Question is by using these shortcodes are there any bad effects when it comes to **SEO** and **page indexing** by search engines.

Why I have this doubt is because I am using another plugin to count the words on each page. The page which uses shortcode showing fewer words even it has more words.

So I just wanted an answer for this one.

Thanks

Comment: I would avoid using that plugin or any other plugin that runs PHP code from the database. Aside from being a dead end from a development point of view, with a lot of disadvantages, it's a major security risk

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell for your thoughts I will think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Search engines can only browse and index the final output of the page, which includes the shortcode output. Your word count plugin is only counting the words entered into the post editor. Those two things work completely differently.